# My wordpress blog posts page is broken

Tags: plugins

I used wordfence plugin to clean unwanted files from my site. Post this, my posts page is broken. If i try to load any of my posts page, page will load but without header, footer, css. Homepage looks fine. Posts page works normal if i'm logged in.
here's one of my post url: https://m.androidestate.com/xiaomi-redmi-k20-pro/
Please let me know what went wrong. BTW i'm newbie :(
Update: Wierdly, some pages are loading as expected. https://m.androidestate.com/asus-rog-phone-ii/

Comment: Your google ads are throwing errors, that may be breaking some of your header code.  If you don't provide code samples of the areas in question then it's hard to help.

Comment: actually post pages are working normally when i'm logged in. So, may be it's not because of ads

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how it could happend, but it only on `m.androidstate.com` I tried the one without subdomain, it worked well.

I just want to recommend you to disable the plugin first, and check the `single.php` or the post page, whether there is `get_header()` or not.

Answer (score 0):

remove .htaccess then go Settings > permalinks > click save twice